# DateTimeFormatter create pattern

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing, java-time

I have this date: `2008-01-10T11:00:00-05:00`(date, T(separator), time, offset)

I have this: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddSEPARATORHH-mm-ssOFFSET")`

I use this [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) to create my pattern.

But, I don't find how to note `SEPARATOR`(T) and OFFSET.

For OFFSET exists this:  `x zone-offset offset-x +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;`, but don't know how to use `x` to get `-08:30`

Comment: Why not use [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME)?

Comment: There is a predefined [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). which just parses the `String` you provided.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thanks.

Comment: As @deHaar said, you can just use the built-in [formatter `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). To answer your question about format pattern letter `x` more directly, it’s under **Offset X and x**, and I quote: *Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.* So you would have needed `xxx`. For the delimiter: *'       escape for text             delimiter*. So enclose the `T` in quotes: `'T'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a little example that shows how to parse your `String` and receive the offset:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this is what you have, a datetime String with an offset
    String dateTime = "2008-01-10T11:00:00-05:00";
    // create a temporal object that considers offsets in time
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTime);
    // just print them in two different formattings
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
    // get the offset from the object
    ZoneOffset zonedOffset = offsetDateTime.getOffset();
    // get its display name (a String representation)
    String zoneOffsetString = zonedOffset.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault());
    // and print the result
    System.out.println("The offset you want to get is " + zoneOffsetString);
}
```

> Please pay attention to the code comments, they explain what is done. Printing the `OffsetDateTime` two times in the middle of the code is just done in order to show how you can deal with a single datetime object along with different formatters.